# Cursor to this method

Tags: android-room

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
>   (android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData>).

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Update
    void update(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);

    @Query("DELETE FROM note_table")
    void deleteAllNotes();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY priority DESC")
    LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes();

}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When using `androidx.room.*` please make sure to use `androidx.lifecycle.LiveData` instead of `android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData` or downgrade to [pre-AndroidX versions of Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#version_111_3)